# Why does the column menu in a Kendo UI grid cause an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Code to create the grid:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [],
    columnMenu: true,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: false,
    filterable: true,
    groupable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "Id",
        title: "Id",
        filterable: false
    }, {
        field: "title",
        title: "Title"
    }]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

I have also customized Array's prototype in this way:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    "use strict";

    if (!this.prototype[name]) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
    }
};

Array.method('contains', function (object) {
    return $.inArray(object, this) !== -1;
});
```

Result: whenever I try to open the column menu for any column, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
```

See a demonstration of the bug at http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/sNdVR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a flaw in kendoColumnMenu (affects versions up to 2013.2.1002) which leads to a bug under the following conditions:

1. Array.prototype is changed to have additional methods, e.g. "contains"
2. Grid options contain columnMenu: true

The private var "template" in kendoColumnMenu needs to be changed: in the for loop, add a check for hasOwnProperty in the following form:

```
'#if (columns.hasOwnProperty(col)) {#' +
```

The complete template would then be:

```
var template = '<ul>' +
'#if(sortable){#' +
'<li class="k-item k-sort-asc"><span class="k-link"><span class="k-sprite k-i-sort-asc"></span>${messages.sortAscending}</span></li>' +
'<li class="k-item k-sort-desc"><span class="k-link"><span class="k-sprite k-i-sort-desc"></span>${messages.sortDescending}</span></li>' +
'#if(showColumns || filterable){#' +
'<li class="k-separator"></li>' +
'#}#' +
'#}#' +
'#if(showColumns){#' +
'<li class="k-item k-columns-item"><span class="k-link"><span class="k-sprite k-i-columns"></span>${messages.columns}</span><ul>' +
'#for (var col in columns) {#' +
'#if (columns.hasOwnProperty(col)) {#' +
'<li><input type="checkbox" data-#=ns#field="#=columns[col].field.replace(/\"/g,"&\\#34;")#" data-#=ns#index="#=columns[col].index#"/>#=columns[col].title#</li>' +
'#}#' +
'#}#' +
'</ul></li>' +
'#if(filterable){#' +
'<li class="k-separator"></li>' +
'#}#' +
'#}#' +
'#if(filterable){#' +
'<li class="k-item k-filter-item"><span class="k-link"><span class="k-sprite k-filter"></span>${messages.filter}</span><ul>' +
'<li><div class="k-filterable"></div></li>' +
'</ul></li>' +
'#}#' +
'</ul>';
```

The only way to fix this at the moment is to edit kendo UI's source code for kendoColumnMenu.